# Jquery Append Json data for hidden input value

Tags: jquery, json

I am getting the data in json format as

```
{"a":null,"b":1001}
```

and I have hidden field as

```
<input type="hidden" name="test" >
```

Now I need to set the value of field test as 1001 on page load. With jquery I am able to get the value in json but for some reason not getting as how do i set 1001 as value to hidden field.

Updated info.

Below is function I m using

```
$.get( "getjobscategoryid", {subcategory:data} )
    .done(function(json ) {   
        alert( "Data Loaded: " + json);
        $('input[name=subcategoryid]').val(json.jobscategoryid); 
        alert(json.jobscategoryid);
    });
```

data is the variable I m passing after capturing the text on page load.After I capture the text, I pass it to jquery get call and I can see that values are coming back perfectly.

and I get data as `Data Loaded:[{"jobscategory":null,"jobscategoryid":1001}]`

Not sure as why i get undefined message for alert.Let me check agian.

Comment: where is jQuery code you tried

Answer (score 3):

> Not sure as why i get undefined message for alert.

Because `json` is a **string** and strings don't have a `jobscategoryid` property. You have to **parse** the JSON into an object/array first.

```
$.get( "getjobscategoryid", {subcategory:data} ).done(function(json ) {
    var = $.parseJSON(json);
    $('input[name=subcategoryid]').val(data[0].jobscategoryid); 
});
```

See also [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

---

How do I know that `json` is a string you may ask? Because

```
alert( "Data Loaded: " + json);
```

gives you

```
Data Loaded:[{"jobscategory":null,"jobscategoryid":1001}]
```

**If** `json` was an object or array, you would get

```
Data Loaded: [object Object]
```

as output, because the default string representation of an object is `[object Object]`.

Comment: +1 for **How do I know that json is a string you may ask? Because**

Answer (score 2):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U4Nfb/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var jsonValue  = { "a": null, "b": 1001 };
    $('input[name=test]').val(jsonValue['b']);
});
```

Comment: {"a":null,"b":1001} this is format of response I am getting and I am interested in setting 1001 as value to hidden field.you example  seems to be more of the string value rather than json

Comment: You can set your json result to that variable.  Look at my example now.

Comment: @KingKongFrog downvoting other wont help you my friend

Comment: @KingKongFrog thats really funny..why would I downvote you my friend..this is bad attitude

Answer (score 0):

this query very use full.

```
//returns {"exists":1} 0-open,1-already exist 
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( JSON.stringify(res) );

            if(obj.id){
            //$("#Language").html(obj.id);
            $('input[name=Language]').val(obj.id);
            }
```